Pachelbel's Canon in D major is related to which Hindustani Music Raga
I once listened to Pachelbel's canon in D major and i love it
I am an Indian and also Know a bit about Hindustani Classical Music, and in Classical music every song can be expressed as the derivation of some raga..
So I was thinking which one which Raga is pachelbel's Canon in D major based on ...or atleast Related to.

Western scales and modes don't have direct equivalents among ragas; see this question. One of the things that's notable about this piece is some moments that use a lowered seventh scale degree (not always). I don't know much about specific ragas, but if I google "raga with lowered 7" I get the suggestion of jhinjhoti.
